# Variable from __init__ changed in one function, but not recognized as changed to other function

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, object-oriented-database

Sup, i'm doing a little account registration just for learning propose.
I created a class called Accounts and did many different functions to work with. With previous acknowledgment i knew that i need to start them from a function called `def __init__(self)`

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contas = {}
        self.bancodecontas = open("x.txt", 'r')

    def getaccounts(self):
        for linha in self.bancodecontas:
            linha = linha.strip()
            conta = linha.split(",")
            login = conta[0]
            senha = conta[1]
            self.contas[login] = senha

    def accountsprinting(self):
        for login, senha in self.contas.items():
            print("Login= ", login, "Senha= ", senha)
```

`getaccounts()` is working fine, i tested a `print(self.contas)` in the end of it and it printed all accounts from inside my x.txt. The problem start when i need to call `accountsprinting()`, i tried to start it with `print(self.contas)` but shows me a empty dictionary, which means it is not accessing the "new" `self.contas`. I did the exact samething in a different type of project and it worked fine, i know i'm missing something really obvious here, so i'm asking sorry beforehand for my lack of attention.
Thanks for your time, good codding.

> EDIT 1

People asked for the entire program, this is my entire program. I'm using PyCharm, i created this as a `accounts.py`, a root file or resources file, and i'm going to be importing this class to another `main.py` to use the respective functions. I know i must call `Accounts().getaccounts()` first, then i must call the other functions, so i can first fill my "accounts database". Even doing this:

Adding `print(self.contas)` to the end of `getaccounts()` and the start of `accountsprinting()`

And doing on the same .py:

```
Account().getaccounts()
Account().accountsprinting()
```

Or doing on different .py:

```
from AccountManager import Account
Account().getaccounts()
Account().accountsprinting()
```

The output is the same: 
`{'Bruno': '666', 'Bruno2': '444', 'Pedro': '2222a', 'Breno': '092b'}`
`{}`

> EDIT 2

Adding `self.getaccounts()`to `def __init__(self)` as @Darkonaut said, really worked, on the same .py and even doing an import from another .py, but i would like to understand why without it, it doesn't work, makes no sense to me.
Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Please provide a short **complete** program that demonstrates the error. see [mcve] for more information.

Comment: For example, when I create a [short complete program](https://ideone.com/0D7uVf), it works fine. Since the code you've posted works correctly, the problem must lie in the code you didn't post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `self.getaccounts()` in the last line of your `__init__` method, hence contas remains empty because it never get's filled.

---

**TL;DR Make sure you keep a reference to a newly created instance to keep it alive
 and perform following method calls on *this* instance.**

`__init__` is a method which is being called after an instance get's created
and *initializes* the instance. You create an instance of a class every time
you call a class like you did with `Account()`.

But if you don't keep a (external) reference to this newly created instance,
you can't address the instance to invoke further methods on it. What happens in your code:

```
Account().getaccounts() # new instance of Account created,
# i.a. __init__ called, finally getaccounts called

Account().accountsprinting() # new instance of Account created,
# i.a. __init__ called, finally accountsprinting called
```

Both instances are quickly garbage collected (CPython implementation of Python assumed), because you don't hold an external reference to them, like you would do if you assign a new instance to a name like: `acc = Account()`.

You can check that you get a new object every time you call `Account()` by comparing identity with `Account(1) is Account(1) # False` or by looking at the `id` numbers:

```
id(Account(1))
# 88311904
id(Account(1))
# 88312408
```

As a side note:

It doesn't have to be a named reference like `acc` above, you could also hold an
implicit, unnamed reference by placing the new instances in a list for example and the list would keep the reference to the instances and thus, keeping them alive:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

lst = [Account(1), Account(2)]
lst[0].x
# 1
lst[1].x
# 2
```

---

`self` in your code is an (internal) reference connecting (binding) class and instance.
If you assign to `self` like you do with `self.contas[login] = senha` within your instance-method `getaccounts`, you do this only for the *actual* instance where you are calling `getaccounts` upon. So when you call `Account().getaccounts()` and
later `Account().accountsprinting()` you are doing this for two different
instances and not on the same. Hence the second instance has an empty `contas` dict because for *this* instance you didn't call `getaccounts()` before.

Comment: He could still call `getaccounts()` after initializing a new object. Since he didn't show a complete program I'm guessing he's not creating an object but rather calling the methods directly from the class.

Comment: @A Magoon If he would do that he probably wouldn't have to wonder about empty contas unless the file is empty of course.

Comment: It worked, but as @AMagoon said, i could still call getaccounts() and then after that call accountsprinting() and it should work, my question is, why are accountsprinting() not using the new self.contas that getaccounts() "did"

Comment: @Bruno Cerk You are creating a new instance every time when you call `Account()`, so the methods are called on separate instances every time. Instantiate one account `account = Account()` and then do all your subsequent method calls on this: `account.getaccounts()` and so on...

Comment: So then i do account = Account() i'm kind saying that account.getaccounts() and account.accountsprinting() are on the same instance, if i don't make it, getaccounts() will happen on some kind of "Instance1" and accountsprinting() on "Instance 2", so on instance 2, my database is empty

Comment: @Bruno Cerk I think you understood it basically. You need to hold a reference to the created instance if you want to invoke further methods on **that** instance.

Comment: Thanks very much, i understand now

Answer (score 2):

You need to create AND use the same instance to call both methods with your expected results.

```
acc = Account()
accounts = acc.getaccounts()
acc.accountsprinting()
```

Also, you import `Accounts` but you call `Account` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i edited it, can you see my last comment on the answer above? I commented about what i understand of it, could you say if i'm correct?